# Loading a project in vs2013 with IIS setting fails

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, iis-7, visual-studio-2013

I have a solution in Visual Studio 2013 that have 8 projects.

The web project for that solution have the IIS setting with the path `http://localhost/www.myproject.com` but every time i open the solution this project gives a "load failed" and if i try to reload the project appears a message that says:
"The URL `http://localhost/www.myproject.com` for web project 'myproject' is configured on the local IIS web server. To open this project, you must use IIS Manager to remove the bindings using this URL from the local IIS web server."
I try to found this bindings without luck.
Every time i ending with this fix:
Editing the myproject.csproj in the code:

```
<ProjectExtensions>
    <VisualStudio>
      <FlavorProperties GUID="{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21}">
        <WebProjectProperties>
          <UseIIS>True</UseIIS>
          <AutoAssignPort>True</AutoAssignPort>
          <DevelopmentServerPort>19384</DevelopmentServerPort>
          <DevelopmentServerVPath>/</DevelopmentServerVPath>
          <IISUrl>http://localhost/www.glocalapps.com</IISUrl>
          <NTLMAuthentication>False</NTLMAuthentication>
          <UseCustomServer>False</UseCustomServer>
          <CustomServerUrl>
          </CustomServerUrl>
          <SaveServerSettingsInUserFile>False</SaveServerSettingsInUserFile>
        </WebProjectProperties>
      </FlavorProperties>
    </VisualStudio>
  </ProjectExtensions>
```

and changing the line `<UseIIS>True</UseIIS>` to False. Then i reload the project and works perfectly only that in the web properties it is set to use IIS Express having to change it again to IIS.

What is going on? Do i have a better solution?

Comment: Have you tried launching Vs in Admin Mode? Try That

Comment: I always launch VS in admin mode.

Comment: Well you might look at the project properties > web section and make some adjustment over there.That might work out.Well in My Box it has only two option IIS express and other is customUrl.That might be beacuse I dont have IIS on my box.

Comment: I have the similar issue, but I want to use IIS instead of IISExpress. Every time I reopen the sln, the changes are revert back.

Answer (score 0):

Answering if someone facing this issue of "project load failed in VS" when IIS is configured to use this project.

You will need to edit bind settings in IIS manager for website configured to use the project